# How do we set 'expiration time', when we create new key with OpenPGP?

Tags: javascript, openpgp, openpgp.js

In OpenPGP.js we have a function `Key.prototype.getExpirationTime`, wich "returns the expiration time of the primary key or null if key does not expire":
https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/src/key.js#L472

But how do we set this expiration time, when we create new key? 
I do not see in this function https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/src/key.js#L938 or in documentation for it https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/module-key.html parameters for 'expiration time'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [OpenPGP.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs) this not implemented yet, see : https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues/511#issuecomment-272376745

For now the simplest solution I see is to use [kbpgp.js](https://github.com/keybase/kbpgp) for key generation, like this: https://ageyev.github.io/crypto/openpgp/ It needs more time for key generation than OpenPGP.js, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple like:

```
let expires = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 // seconds to expire keys {Number}
let PGPOptions = {
    userIds: [{
        name: 'username',
        email: 'awesome@mail.com'
    }],
    numBits: 2048,                // RSA
    passphrase: 'good passphrase' // protects the private key
    keyExpirationTime: expires    // 30 days
}
// create keys (pub/priv)
openpgp.generateKey(PGPOptions).then(key => {
    let privkey = key.privateKeyArmored,
        pubkey = key.publicKeyArmored
})
```